# Error: req#logout requires a callback function in passport version 0.6.0

Tags: node.js, passport.js

im creating an app to signup and logout user in the same session. when im using passport version 0.6.0 it gives me an error Error: req#logout requires a callback function". i revised from internet but there isn't an exact answer for the solution.
"https://medium.com/passportjs/fixing-session-fixation-b2b68619c51d"
i mean i need to signup the user and logout the same user. but  in the above solution they redirected the user to homepaege. can anyone tell me how tosolve this issue..
thanks in advance..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8K2b.png)

i need not to navigte to homepage and at the sametime i need to show two messages,

1. logged out
   2.No User to Log out

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: ive added a screenshot. and i need the same route fr logout without error.